# podman-composer: maintaining correct file ownership between host and container

Tags: podman

Here is a problem.  Here is a part of my podman-compose.yml

```
  web:
    build: .
    args:
      USERNAME: ${USERNAME}
      GROUPNAME: ${GROUPNAME}
      USERID: ${USERID}
      GROUPID: ${GROUPID}
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo
      - TERM=xterm-256color
      - PGHOST=db
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://db
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=password
      - APP_HOST=web
    userns: keep-id

    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
     - .:/app:z
```

This is the call to the podman composer:

```shell
podman-compose up --build-arg USERNAME=$(id -un) --build-arg GROUPNAME=$(id -gn) --build-arg USERID=$(id -u) --build-arg GROUPID=$(id -g)
```

Volume for the `web` is supposed to be write-accessible from the container and from the host.

In this configuration correspondent folder inside the container and files inside are root owned.  If I add a 'U' flag, like this:  `- .:/app:z,U`, folder became write-accessible to the container, but locally, on host it became owned by the user with uid 100999  and gid 100999.

But when I run resulting container with the command

```shell
podman run -it -v .:/home/lesha:z --userns=keep-id  --entrypoint /bin/sh quotes_web:latest
```

Ownership is correct inside the container and doesn't changed on the host and everything works as supposed.  Any suggestions to fix it for the composer?

This is a Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.0.0-alpine

ARG USERNAME
ARG GROUPNAME
ARG USERID
ARG GROUPID

COPY run_rails.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run_rails.sh

WORKDIR /app

ENV APPPATH='/app'

RUN echo '***' && \
    addgroup -g $GROUPID $GROUPNAME && \
    adduser -S -u $USERID -G $GROUPNAME  -h /home/$USERNAME -s /bin/sh $USERNAME && \
    mkdir -p /home/$USERNAME && \
    chmod 700 /home/$USERNAME && \
    mkdir -p $APPPATH && \
    echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin" >> /home/$USERNAME/.profile && \
    echo 'gem: --user-install --env-shebang --no-rdoc --no-ri' >> /home/$USERNAME/.gemrc && \
    echo "Change ownership chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUPNAME $APPPATH" && \
    chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUPNAME $APPPATH && \
    chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUPNAME /home/$USERNAME

USER $USERNAME
ENTRYPOINT ["run_rails.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.  Works for me with `userns_mode: keep-id` instead of `userns: keep-id`